# Unable to choose whether Free or Paid android app

Tags: android, youtube

I am trying to build a small Android application. Basically in this app, i will configure some useful videos URLs from YouTube in a SQLite or Mongo database(db). My application read data from this db and displays in the application.

I would like to show couple of pointers to these videos as free, but for full access i am planning to make this as paid.

Will there be any legal challenges from YouTube, if i make the full version as Paid?

Comment: Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to choose as free app since the YoutubeApi is free up to a limit.